# hosting stating static files to www domain in wasabi is not working

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, wasabi

i have my s3 buckets in wasabi.

Need to host the site via CDN

i saw cloudflare but it had issues on www , other subdomain CNAME works; but www gets redirected to wasabi.com . They call it "CNAME flattering on the root domain". I want to disable it.